# Systematic or random error when using camera to record worm position

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

We have carried out an experiment where the worm position at each time frame was recorded using a camera and appropriate software, returning the pixel position of the worms as their centre of mass.

When thinking about the error on the position of the worm we are unsure on whether it is systematic, random or a combination of both?

Answer (score 0):

Systematic error is pretty straightforward: you have a coordinate system:

$$ (x_{worm}, y_{worm}, z_{worm}) $$.

OK, so it's flat, get rid of $z$:

$$ (x_{worm}, y_{worm}) $$

well how flat is it? That's a systematic bias, one that is not unrelated to the camera position and pointing angle. Estimating all that requires detailed understanding of your set up.

Anytime you quantize something, you get quantization noise (of which, much has been written). Quantifying that requires an understanding of your worm detection algorithm. I would simulated it with a Monte Carlo: input simulated worms with known position, and see how it's captured in pixels and how its center-of-mass reconstruction error behaves. (You may also have to investigate the validity of the uniform-density-worm hypothesis: how much error is cause by density variations in a real worm?). How well can you even define a worm position? Do you need to consider higher moments, e.g., the worm-quadruple moment?

True random error is going to come from noise. So, imagine a low SNR set up, where an empty pixel is 0 and worm filled pixel is 1 (in theory)....and add something like exponential noise or gaussian noise (depends on the illumination and detector properties). So instead of an empty pixel being intensity $I=0$, it's distributed according to:

$$ P_{empty}(I) = e^{-I/I_{Noise}} $$

where $I_{Noise}<1$

(hopefully).

Meanwhile, a worm pixel may have gaussian behavior:

$$ P_{worm}(I) \propto e^{-\frac{(I-1)^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$

That is going to give you false worms and missed worms depending on the worm detection threshold: $I_{worm}$.

So understanding that requires a deep dive into you detection hardware and analysis software.